# How can I get a MS Access Union query make a table?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I've finally gotten my hands on MS Access 2010, and I'm unioning some tables.

I'd like to output that union to a (static) table, but if I select the Make Table option it wipes the union query you've just written, and vice versa.

This is trivial to do in SQL (`Select * into A from( Select tbl1.col1 from tbl1 UNION Select tbl2.col2 from tbl2` or somethign similar)

But is it possible to do just by pressing buttons?

Comment: Why the close vote? This is an sql question, of which there are quite a few on SO, so it cannot be off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible with pressing buttons. Use sql view of the query design window.